# Telegram setwebhook not receiving updates

Tags: php, google-app-engine, ssl-certificate, telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot

I am using Google Cloudshell platform to create an ssl-certified url for hosting a webhook. So I originally began using getupdates to find the chat_id and send the bot messages. The following code, meant to get the user's chat-id and then text him "text" , works fine.

```
<?php 
$botToken = "insert bot token" ;
$website = "https://api.telegram.org/bot".$botToken ;

$update = file_get_contents($website."\getupdates");
$updateArray = json_decode($update, TRUE) ;

$chatId = $updateArray["result"][0]["message"]["chat"]["id"] ;
file_get_contents($website."/sendmessage?chat_id=".$chatId."&text=test") ;
?>
```

Then I set up a webhook using setwebhook and modified the above code.

```
<?php 
$botToken = "insert bot token" ;
$website = "https://api.telegram.org/bot".$botToken ;

$update = file_get_contents("php://input");
$updateArray = json_decode($update, TRUE) ;

$chatId = $updateArray["result"][0]["message"]["chat"]["id"] ;
file_get_contents($website."/sendmessage?chat_id=".$chatId."&text=test") ;
?>
```

In other words I changed the \getupdates with "php://input" . It did **not** work.

I suppose it is possible that google app engine does not automatically sign its ssl certificates and perhaps that's why the webhook does not work.

Any help will be appreciated.

**EDIT :**  In response to the answers/comment below, I tried the getWebhookinfo approach and got

"url:"https://my_url.com" ,"has_custom_certificate":false, "pending_update_count":0, "max_connections":40

Comment: You can get more information by using the `/webhookinfo` method. Please post the result of this.

Comment: @creyD So this gives a "url:"https.url" ,"has_custom_certificate":false, "pending_update_count":0, "max_connections":40

Comment: Yeah the url isn´t right. You have to adjust this with the `/setwebhook` method. Example: `/setwebhook?url=https://www.google.de` documented [here](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#setwebhook).

Comment: @creyD no I intentionally replaced my actual url with the silly "https :url" ; however, the "has_custom_certificate":false statement seems to imply that it doesn't have an ssl certificate yet. I tried to find how to get an ssl cert from google app engine but failed.

Comment: No the `has_custom_certificate = false` is okay, has nothing to do with SSL. But yes, you´ll need a https adress otherwise it just doesn´t work properly. I guess you tried [this](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/using-custom-domains-and-ssl) already..

Answer (score 0):

You can find out problem via following method:

Check [getWebhookInfo](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getwebhookinfo) method, make sure your webhook URL is correct, and no `last_error_message` field.

POST similar data to your server, [here](https://core.telegram.org/bots/webhooks#testing-your-bot-with-updates) is some data you can use in `curl -d JSON`, just copy it and run on your own server.

At last, check your CDN config (if you had applied on that server), temporary disable flooding or any check.

Comment: Thank you for answering. The getWebhookInfo yields   "url:"https.url" ,"has_custom_certificate":false, "pending_update_count":0, "max_connections":40

Comment: The problem, I believe is, with app engine's app.yaml file in which I need to add in a secure parameter .